# Why does this SQL query work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am following [Phil Greenspun's tutorial on SQL.](http://philip.greenspun.com/sql/introduction.html)

Phil uses Oracle for the tutorial but I am using MySQL. Here are my queries:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE mailing (
    -> email varchar(100) not null primary key,
    -> name varchar(100)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO mailing (email, name) VALUES ('foo@bar.com', 'FooBar');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE phone (
    -> email varchar(100) not null references mailing,
    -> phone varchar(20)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, I have set the `email` column of `phone` table to be a reference.

The tutorial says:

> The `phone` table has a referential
>   integrity constraint ("references
>   `mailing`") to make sure that we don't
>   record e-mail addresses for people
>   whose names we don't know

Then how come this query works?:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO phone (email, phone) VALUES ('new@new.com', '112223');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

... note that I don't have `new@new.com` in the `mailing` table.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Nemoden's answer:

Your next problem will be Phil's example with the check constraint which is not supported by MySQL at all (and there is no storage engine that does this).

Comment: Yep. I've forgotten this issue. Thank you for help on composing blanket answer to this question.

Comment: Ouch. That is bad. I *really* like his tutorial but if I keep on running into such problems, it will be bad! I wonder why SQL is still not standardized.

Comment: SQL **is** standardized, only MySQL doesn't comply with the standard here. If you want to follow the tutorial you can either use Oracle XE (free) or simply go for PostgreSQL (free)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks! I will go with Postgre.

Comment: @AA: Just a small hint: it's either Postgres, PostgreSQL or simply pg. Never Postgre (without an s) ;)

Answer (score 5):

References in MySQL are available only for InnoDB engine, rewrite your CREATE TABLE as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE phone (
    -> email varchar(100) not null references `mailing` (`email`),
    -> phone varchar(20)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

By default, MySQL uses MyISAM engine that ignores "references" statement.
Read more [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) on creating tables in MySQL

UPDATE: 
The foreign key reference must be placed outside the CREATE TABLE statement. Thanks, @jswolf and @a_horse_with_no_name

```
CREATE TABLE phone (
-> email varchar(100) not null,
-> phone varchar(20),
-> REFERENCES `mailing` (`email`)
-> ON DELETE NO ACTION
-> ON UPDATE NO ACTION
-> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Did not test, but more likely it will work.

Comment: Did you check that? According to the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), "Furthermore, InnoDB does not recognize or support “inline `REFERENCES` specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification."

Comment: @Nemoden: I am still able to insert the values.

Comment: @Nemoden: jswolf is correct. The foreign key reference must be placed outside the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not work with references specifically in MySQL. So, no - I did not. But, anyway, it explains the main question: why create table query works there: because it's correct MySQL CREATE TABLE syntax.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yep. Shame on me - I'll take a time to fulfill this gap in my MySQL experience.

Comment: @Nemodon: no problem. I think it's a shame that MySQL ignores it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, hope guys from Oracle will do something about it. Not respecting standards is not the way software is building.

Comment: MySQL's been slow with foreign key support in general. The way I remember it being explained to me was that MySQL devs were concerned with getting the performance of a subset good and then adding on slowly without hurting performance. Subqueries were also added rather late...

Comment: @Nemoden: It doesn't have to be outside of the CREATE TABLE statement. Inside but after the fields declarations, as FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Answer (score 1):

As Nemoden's answer, you should use InnoDB, not MyISAM.

The `FOREIGN KEY` relationship can (and should in MYSQL) be added like this:

```
CREATE TABLE phone
( email varchar(100) NOT NULL
, phone varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL

, FOREIGN KEY fk_mailing (email)         --- the "fk_mailing" name is optional
    REFERENCES mailing (email)
) 
  ENGINE=InnoDB 
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 ;               --- or other charset you prefer
```

From the tutorial you use:

> I'm using MySQL, and I wanted to comment on a snag I ran into while
>     I was following the tutorial in this page. Maybe other newbies can benefit from this.
>
> As far as I can tell:
>
> a) MySQL supports different "storage engines" for tables. This is presumably
>     a good thing. However, not all engines support referencial constraints.
>
> b) For a MySQL table to support a "references" constraint, it must be of type InnoDB.
>     In my installation (on SuSE Linux, right out of a standard RPM binary package), this
>     is *not* the default. So you have to either change the server configuration to make
>     this the default, or specify "ENGINE = InnoDB" after the closing parenthesis in the
>     table definition.
>
> c) Even for InnoDB, the syntax described by Phil above does not work, though it is
>     **not rejected, merely ignored**. According to the manual, this is effectively **just a
>     comment** to the developer that this column is supposed to reference another column,
>     even if the constraint is not enforced by mysql.
>
> d) So, the only way to make this kind of constraint work is to: 1. make the table
>     InnoDB and 2. use the "FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES mailing_list(email)" format
>     as a separate entry inside the table definition.
>
> [MySQL won't even give a warning! Not even a reminder that such reference clauses
>     are merely "comments". It will just happily ignore them and allow any old value in
>     that row. Ugh.]
>
> ```
>   -- Antonio Ramirez, March 19, 2007
> ```